# How to Play Video File On D Drive In WinRT?

Tags: c#, video, windows-8, windows-runtime

Using XAML C# in Windows "Metro" Apps how do I go about playing a certain video file. Examples:

- D:\video1.wmv
- \\MEDIAPC\video2.wmv

The only way I managed to get this working so far is by using FilePicker, but I don't want to use this as I already have a list of files to play.

I have tried to use GetFileFromPathAsync but I keep getting permission / access issues

```
 await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"D:\video1.wmv");
```

Apologies if this has been answered I just couldn't find an answer that fits my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "I already have a list of files to play"?  A FilePicker (or being passed a file stream to open when your app is activated) is the normal way to accomplish this.  Windows Store apps can't normally just load random files from wherever they please.

Comment: I have a background service that catalogs media, now I simply want to play that target file (as I've already gone through the painstaking process of identifying it). This background service is a windows service and doesn't have these access restrictions.

Comment: Check out the links that ShelbyZ posted.  You can declare your app to require access to the user's music library and then you can access files in there, but you can't just access random files on disk, even if you find out about them from some service running in the background that's already been installed through full trust.  Declaring the proper capabilities for the music library and network shares will mostly get you what you need, though you may still have to work around the fact that you won't always have filenames like you're used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your D:\ drive is a non-network resource try adding the Removable storage application capability.  This can be accomplished by double-clicking on the Package.appxmanifest and navigating to the Capabilities tab.  By default your application (assuming it is a Windows Store app) only has access to local files packaged with your app or files stored in local/roaming/temp folders (usually reserved for Application state).

If your data is stored on a Network resource that requires authentication you will want to enable the Enterprise Authentication capability.

You may also want to fiddle with the Home and Work Networks for the \MEDIAPC\ files if you aren't accessing resources that require network authentication.

Further Reads:

- [Accessing data and files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758319)
- [How to load data from files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322)
- [App Capabilities Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#removable_storage)