# How do I play a Media File Stored in D drive using Windows Store App C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a List box Containing the Media file path. When i am Selecting the item(path) from the List Box It supposed to play in the Media Element... 
How do i do?
Thanks,
Sankar.

```
private async void btnLoadPlayList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker filePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
    filePicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mpeg");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mkv");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".3gp");

    IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile> fileList = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
    if (fileList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
        {
            lstPlayList.Items.Add(file.Path);
        }
    }
}
private async void lstPlayList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        PlayerME2.Source = new Uri(lstPlayList.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

If i am setting the source like this, and try to play then, it shows Error E Access Denied Exception. Tell me something to set the source and play the selected file.

Comment: Show us what you having so far,..

Comment: is this makes any sense @kumar- I m badly new to this. help in some way. thanks

Comment: The same thing here.. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322242/read-the-value-of-an-item-in-a-listbox?answertab=votes#tab-top ]

Comment: Get the selected item from playlist. & Play the media file using the filepath..

Comment: dude, i don't know how to set the source and play the file., i need the syntax .. :) @kumar

Comment: [http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/basic-media-playback-003619be ] Let me know that you find the solution or not.. Be specific   on your question..

Comment: @kumar, still not able to solve the problem. lets forget everything. Now, i have the path as a string. how do i play a media file using this string. that's it.

Comment: Did my answer helps you or not?

Comment: sorry dude. its not working for me :( . i don't know what mistake i have done. Can u give your mail id, I ll send my application to u , so that u can easily find my bug. :) @kumar

Comment: Do one thing.. Upload Zip file to [https://onedrive.live.com/ ]. Use the share option.
paste the link here..

Comment: @kumar
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ABFB99CA61081112!512&authkey=!AEqz0IP5znAgpqs&ithint=file%2c.rar

Comment: I didn't get why you are trying to customize media element with slider & button. Look at the scenario 3 in this sample to customize media element.. [http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/basic-media-playback-003619be ]

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963058/how-to-play-video-file-on-d-drive-in-winrt?answertab=votes#tab-top)'s the Link you have to fallow. You have to give access capability in appManifest.

Apart from this you can use [stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream)

```
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
```

Look at the scenario 5 in the sample I posted  in Last comment.

```
    StorageFile file = Playlist.SelectedItem as StorageFile;

    if (file != null)
    {
        // Open the selected file and set it as the MediaElement's source
        IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        Scenario5MediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
    }
```

Hope this Helps